# fullCalendar Jquery plugin not appearing on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

I have tried to add the fullCalendar jquery to a view in my MVC 4 project. When I try to laod the page there are no errors but the calendar does not appear on the page. I am not sure why it isn't appearing and I have looked at the documentation and it looks like I got everything covered.

```
Here is my HTML:

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Calendar";
}

<h2>Calendar</h2>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calendar</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/fullcalendar.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/fullcalendar.print.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/moment.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/jquery.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/jquery-ui.custom.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/fullcalendar.min.js")"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="calendar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

HERE IS MY CSS:

```
#calendar {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 40px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add refs to the libs you want to use;

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
<script src='fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
```